# Azure VM RDP outbound NSG rule

Tags: azure, security, networking, port, rdp

[image: My NSG rules]I want to secure my web server vm to limit mainly to 443 and 3389 ports strictly. I denied everything else both outbound and inbound in the NSG for the web vm. But I can't rdp after doing so. When I relax the NSG to allow all outbound, then rdp starts working. My question is what outbound ports and protocols the rdp service needs to be opened in nsg beside 3389?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thesushil: In my case it turns out, I just needed to add an outbound rule to allow Azure AD communication over http and https, because I have azure AD authentication enabled. But I think the answer below would be helpful to others.

---

Be default, the RDP server listens on TCP port 3389 and UDP port 3389. Read [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol). You also could [change the listening port for remote desktop](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306759/how-to-change-the-listening-port-for-remote-desktop).

If you want to secure your Azure VM limit to 443 and 3389 ports, you can add inbound port rules like this to only allow your client-specific IP address to access your Azure VM.

[image]

Also, please note that If inbound traffic is allowed over a port, it's not necessary to
specify an outbound security rule to respond to traffic over the port. Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/security-overview#security-rules

> Network security group security rules are evaluated by priority using
>   the 5-tuple information (source, source port, destination, destination
>   port, and protocol) to allow or deny the traffic. A flow record is
>   created for existing connections. Communication is allowed or denied
>   based on the connection state of the flow record. The flow record
>   allows a network security group to be stateful. If you specify an
>   outbound security rule to any address over port 80, for example, it's
>   not necessary to specify an inbound security rule for the response to
>   the outbound traffic. You only need to specify an inbound security
>   rule if communication is initiated externally. The opposite is also
>   true. **If inbound traffic is allowed over a port, it's not necessary to
>   specify an outbound security rule to respond to traffic over the port**.
>   Existing connections may not be interrupted when you remove a security
>   rule that enabled the flow. Traffic flows are interrupted when
>   connections are stopped and no traffic is flowing in either direction,
>   for at least a few minutes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Nancy for the detailed explanation. I also want to restrict outbound traffic, in case my vm is compromised I don't want it to spread out. So I denied all outbound traffic. After that I see the RDP session initiates but eventually times out. My question is basically what do I need to put in outbound rules to allow RDP. When I added allow outbound 3389 above deny all outbound, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Could you show what is the specific outbound rules？hiding senditive data

Comment: I inserted a pic of my nsg rules in the question, do you need anything else?